# What does "celebrations coalesce in his mind" mean in this paragraph?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> It’s late but not too late. He notices that the big shows are starting to let out, vomiting dandy citizens and intrepid tourists onto the sidewalk from brightly lit lobbies. It’s not too late, he looks at his watch, and ***celebrations coalesce in his mind, festivities to be groped and devoured once he picks up an advance copy of his cover story at the office***.

[Source: The Intuitionist (online novel)](https://onlinereadfreenovel.com/colson-whitehead/page,8,57978-the_intuitionist.amp)

---

I'd like to know what the whole bold part means.

I don't know the grammatical construction of the whole bold part.

Comment: Do you know what "coalesce in his mind" means? You should be able to work that out with a dictionary. The rest of the sentence "festivities...office" is a noun phrase in apposition to "celebrations", and describes the celebrations. There is quite a lot going on in that sentence, so it's not clear exactly what you have a problem with.

Comment: @StuartF I'm not sure what "***coalesce in his mind***" and "***festivities to be groped and devoured***" mean.

Comment: Does it help to point out that these are metaphors?